# PHP: How to get single value from array that was returned from a class?

Tags: php

```
class Test {

    public function results() {

      $return['first'] = 'one';
      $return['second'] = 'two';

      return $return;

    }

}

$test = new Test;

print_r($test->results()); // Returns entire array
```

I just want to return a single specified element from the array, such as the value of key "second". How do I do this without sifting through the entire array after it's returned?

Comment: Just return only one element? `return $return["second"];`

Comment: Your code actually doesn't behave as you say. the `print_r` won't print anything because the function `results()` doesn't return anything. See https://3v4l.org/r3Nog

Comment: nobody mentioned [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/array_shift) yet

Comment: @NDM you'd need multiple calls if not the first element

Comment: @NDM Don't really think a `array_shift()` is necessary in this circumstance, it's really just accessing a value from an array.

Comment: yeah, I read it wrong the first pass :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just want to return a single specified element from the array, such as the value of key "second"

Pass in an argument to identify which element to return, and return that (or false if it doesn't exist - for example);

```
public function results($key = null)
{
    $return['first'] = 'one';
    $return['second'] = 'two';

    // check the key exists
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $return)) {
        return false;
    }

    return $return[$key];
}
```

Then:

```
print_r($test->results('second')); // two
```

> How do I do this without sifting through the entire array after it's returned?

It's important to note that you do not need to "sift through the entire array" to retrieve a value by its key. You know the key, so you can access it directly.

Comment: This should also work I believe `$test->results()['second']`

Comment: @Aaron yes, but array de-referencing is not backwards compatible from 5.4 so I *currently* try and avoid using it in Stackoverflow answers

Comment: not a fan of returning false or value, prevents upward compatibility with return type hints

Comment: 5.4 shouldn't be being run unless security maintained by your OS's package maintainers. I know backports exist however you should aim for 5.6+

Comment: @NDM it's better than a warning when the key doesn't exist :)

Comment: Don't understand why anyone would downgrade to a lower version of php, but yes.

Comment: Turns out array dereferencing was introduced in 5.4 :O

Comment: @Aaron I'm not suggesting a downgrade - just proposing a standardised solution that will work on older versions (which are still widely used)

Comment: @RobbieAverill I know you are not. Both solutions are fine.

Comment: but now you have to wrap this call in an `if`, to check if the result isn't `false`. So you moved the `if` in the function, and gave the user a different `if` to implement... because if he doesn't, he's still getting a runtime warning. so you havent solved the actual problem.

Comment: @NDM you miss the point. If you don't handle undefined indexes, you get notices generated by trying to access undefined indexes. Unless you're suggesting to disable error reporting I think your point it incorrect.

Comment: @NDM What would you suggest? Currently I would just do something like `if ($returned_key) {` Is there a better way than returning the value or `false`?

Comment: @JROB You don't need to check that, as Robbie's function already checks that for you.

Comment: yes, you should definetly add that `if`, but my point is, you build a check in the function, but in return you are required to add a new check, so you gain nothing.

Comment: @Aaron yes he does because the function can return `false` instead of a result

Comment: @RobbieAverill sorry but creating array in method call is not any advice and good practice, this should be not accepted answer.

Comment: @NDM That depends on the context, `false` may be informative.

Comment: @MaciejSikora it's simply copy and pasted from the question

Comment: @Aaron it may be informative, but you will always do the check twice...

Comment: @RobbieAverill i know but this is getter function. You know and You know that it is bad, but others...?

Comment: @MaciejSikora technically speaking it's not a getter, since "get" is not the prefix to the method name. But yes, I agree with you that the actual array assignments should be done in another method.

Comment: @MaciejSikora the data origin is just as an example... it's irrelevant how it's built up

Comment: @NDM Well now it's getting to the point where it's getting too broad and specific at the same time. We don't really know if he wants to check for a false, but it's a good idea to check for a false. We also don't know how this will be used.. list goes on.. If he needs to check for a false, he can do that on his own accord. But Robbie has given him a solution to his original problem.

Comment: if he doesn't want to check the result, why would he want to return anything? he's surely not just gonna `print_r` and `exit`

Comment: @NDM no, we have all code of class pasted, so answer should be not only for method but should refactor all class. Next thing i prefer return null when not boolean types are returned. This is more like in hard typed languges.

Comment: @NDM Yes but that's not his problem. The OP's problem is literally `How to get single value from array that was returned from a class?`

Comment: @RobbieAverill getter not means that method starts from get word.. please getter means it get data.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Test {

  private $arr; //private property of object

  __construct(){

    //create arr in constructor   
    $this->arr=[];//create new array

    $this->arr['first'] = 'one';
    $this->arr['second'] = 'two';

  }

  /**
  /* get array
  **/
  public function getResults(){

     return $this->arr;
  }

  /**
  /* get single array element
  **/
  public function getResult($key) {

     return isset($this->arr[$key])?$this->arr[$key]:null;//return element on $key or null if no result
  }

}

$test = new Test();

print_r($test->getResult("second")); // Returns array element
//or second possibility but the same result
print_r($test->getResults()["second"]); // Returns array element
```

**Few advices:**

Create data structure in constructor ($arr in this particular case) because creating it on very results method call is not any kind of using objects or objective programming. Imagine that if array is created in results method then on every call new array is located in memory, this is not efficent, not optimal and gives no possibility to modify this array inside class Test.

Next in method results add parameter to get only this key what is needed and hide all array in private class property **$arr** to encapsulate it in object.

**And last my private opinion for naming style:**

Use **camelCase** when naming method names.

Comment: `Use camelCase when naming method names.` - while I prefer this style myself, it is a stylistic decision developers should make for themselves

Comment: @RobbieAverill ok i will not argue - I added some information that it is my private opinion

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 5.4 and above:

```
print_r($test->results()['second']);
```

In older versions which you shouldn't be running as they are out of security maintenance:

```
$results = $test->results();
print_r($results['second']);
```

Edit: The first example originally said 5.6 and above but array dereferencing was introduced in 5.4! For the avoidance of doubt, 5.6 is the lowest php version within security maintenance.

Comment: Aside from when dereferencing was introduced, I don't believe that the second example should NOT be used in modern PHP versions. Dereferncing is only one method for accessing data, has its own benefits and drawbacks and I personally think think reduces readability.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP an array value can be dereferenced from the [array](http://php.net/language.types.array) by its key.

```
$arr = ["foo" => "bar", "baz" => "quix"];

echo $arr["foo"]; // gives us "bar"
echo $arr["baz"]; // gives us "quix"
```

If the method/function returns an array the same can be done with the return value, whether by assigning the return value to a variable and using the variable to dereference the value by key, or by using [function array dereferencing](http://php.net/language.types.array#example-105).

```
class Test {

    public function results() {

      return ["foo" => "bar", "baz" => "quix"];

    }     

}

$test = new Test;

$arr = $test->results();
echo $arr["foo"]; // gives us "bar"
echo $arr["baz"]; // gives us "quix"

// Using FAD (Function Array Dereferencing)

echo $test->results()["foo"]; // gives us "bar"
echo $test->results()["baz"]; // gives us "quix"
```

Of course there are two important caveats to using function array dereferencing.

1. The function is executed each time you do it (*i.e no memoziation*)
2. If the key does not exist or the function returns something other than array, you get an error

Which means it's usually safer to rely on assigning the return value to a variable first and then doing your validation there for safety... Unless you are sure the function will always return an array with that key and you know you won't need to reuse the array.

Comment: it should be noted that the function executes multiple times when using FAD.

Comment: Right, I added the caveats. Thanks.